# Can't understand concept 'stiff source'

Tags: power, load, source

What does it mean in itself and in context?. Bolded phrase in section 10.5.2 IEEE Std 519.

> Methods for compensating for existing or potential flicker are much
>   the same as those used to compensate for subtransient disturbances,
>   such as those evidenced by notching or harmonic currents. The simplest
>   and generally most effective technique is to provide a sufficiently
>   stiff source of power so that the effect is negligible at the point
>   where the flicker source is tapped off from the rest of the power
>   distribution system. **Compensatory methods are used to emulate the
>   stiff source**. Series capacitors, thyristor switching of inductors with
>   shunt capacitors (static var control), saturating shunt inductors, and
>   thyristor switched shunt capacitors may be used to maintain a
>   relatively steady voltage at the tie point. As in cases in which such
>   schemes are used to provide subtransient compensation, the possibility
>   of overall distribution system instability must be thoroughly
>   investigated before one can confidently apply the technique.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The other answers are good, but you might find a different approach better. Start with a voltage source and a load. The voltage source will have an output impedance. The circuit will look like

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhyMf7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Let's say that Rout is large. Then changes to the load resistor will cause changes to VLoad. The source (measured at the load resistor) is "elastic". It will vary with changes to the load.

Now let's say that Rout is very small. Then changes to RLoad will have little effect on VLoad. Using the image of the load on the end of a beam, the source is now said to be "stiff". It does not change with changes in load.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's much clear. Now, what would it be, for example, that Rout in power systems? It's located at distribution or generation level?

Comment: @Diegov - For power systems, Rout is determined by every step from the generating plant to the power outlet. Every transformer, every power line will add resistance. Of course, every added resistance wastes power and reduces the efficiency of the system, so such losses are carefully considered and their effects counteracted to the degree economically feasible.

Comment: I was perplexed with the term stiff until you mention "beam". Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It means a relatively low impedance source, compared to the disturbances in the system.

In the context above, it seems the power source needs to have a low impedance in order to minimize the effect of the transient disturbances. By compensatory methods, they mean the the power supply is designed using a control loop or other schemes which "further stiffen" the source: regulation methods lower the effective impedance of the power supply.

Answer (score 1):

"Stiff source" means low source impedance, high ratio of prospective short circuit current / rated current, low effect of source voltage by changing load current.

In the context to IEEE 519, notching is essentially a microsecond range short circuit caused by reverse recovery current of a thyristor. Harmonics are caused by load current with high peaks occurring every cycle.

Answer (score 1):

% "Load regulation" is like a voltage divider with Vout= (Zout/Zout+Zsource)Vin and typically we just say R ratio of load/source for high ratios.  Thus load-dependent  Voltage regulation depends on low Source Z so the output "resists" change in voltage hence "stiff source".

In this case, active power factor using thyristor switches and passive LC components are used to regulate distribution voltage within 5% typically for generation and 5% for distribution with variations in load to stay within tolerance. **Hence stiff source with compensation**.  So when transient inductive or capacitance loads are dominant, grid controls may change to accommodate best  transformer source impedance and tap voltages to improve regulation.

In India it may be not be so well regulated yet for any reasons, but here in Toronto area my voltage is well regulated within a few % year round with rare exceptions. They use a complex network of telemetry at all tie points and neighbourhoods to regulate this and isolate detected faults.

My brother-in-law who is a Prof at U of T in EE Energy networks, recently visited our PowerStream network control and said it was possibly the best in the world ( he has seen or heard) for power regulation and control.  But then our peak demand energy costs were also very high ($175/MWh) but recently rates were rolled back by Premier due to consumer complaints.

We know that Op Amps reduce Output impedance with negative feedback, but this is quasi static and not real-time high BW like an Op Amp, although the compensation has some effect of lowering effective load regulation by occasional changes to these series shunt reactors and caps.